# Smart contract panicked: Sender and receiver should be different

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm having a stake_token function and it transfer token from signer address to current contract address using ft_transfer_call
[image: Here is the code and the error]

In cmd, I have a script call stake_token function. The signer is tungleanh.testnet and receiver is current account id which is the 77037 account. Why does it return Sender and receiver should be different error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On line 92, the contract attempts to transfer FT tokens to `env::current_account_id()`. This evaluates to the contract name, so that dev account ending in 77037. You are calling that account function that thus attempts to send funds to itself.